# Open window application in current window

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, window

I want to open a **game** application replacing the **menu** window.

So I have a game application which I can start with:

```
subprocess.call(["mygameprogram", "argument one"])
```

This opens up another window, but I want to **replace** the qt window with the game window without closing the menu window.

This is my MainWindow class:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.initMenu()
        self.show()

    def initMenu(self):

        # load ui file
        uic.loadUi("somefile.ui", self)

        # add pushbutton
        btn = QPushButton()

        # add click listener
        btn.clicked.connect(self.startLevel)

        # add button to layout
        self.layout_buttons.addWidget(btn)

    def startLevel(self):

        # open game, put the right code in here :D
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there any solution for that? And if not, what should I do instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a strange design choice, to change from the menu to a game you would normally track the 'state' you want to be in, and then have a 'drawing loop' that draws different elements inside the window depending on what state you are in. Then you just need to change the state from menu to game for example.

Comment: Yes that would make things easier, but I have developed the game using a game engine and I want to call the exported game file, because I cannot really change the code of the exported game itself.

Comment: Do you want this to be a "launcher" utility that starts the game, then closes itself?

Comment: No it should start the game in its own window without closing itself.